# Get the mapped path for a resource as it is in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-routing

**TL;DR;**

Is there a way to get a string with the resource mapping just as it is declared in routes.rb, including params names? Eg.:

```
/resource/:id/nested/:nested_id/deep/:deep_id
/resource/:id/nested/:nested_id
/resource/:id
```

I need this string and intend to replace the params manually, maybe with a map like `{id: 1, nested_id:2, deep_id: 3}`

**Reason**

I have a integration where I will receive something like:

```
resource:deep_resource, resource_id:1, extra_args: {id: 1, nested_id:2}
```

or

```
resource:nested_resource, resource_id:1, extra_args: {id: 1}
```

or

```
resource:first_level_resource, resource_id:1, extra_args: {}
```

I intend to replace the values in the url and redirect to the given resource. Maybe with a autofill from the extra_args map to the matching params in the url.

I don't want to do a lot of if/else to call `deep_resource_path(a,b,c)` or `nested_resource_path(a,b)` or `first_level_resource_path(a)`

Note that for the deep resource I need 2 more args(the grandparent id and the parent id). For the nested resource I only need the parent id and for the first_level resource I only need it`s own Id.

So, is it possible?

Thank you.

ps.: I think the map with the args a better option then receive or hard code de full url to redirect for each resource. So, if the url changes in the future, but keep the same params, the redirection can will keep working.

Answer (score 2):

If you pull in the routes url helpers:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

You can then access the path and url helpers directly to get this string. For example, given the following output when running `rake routes`:

```
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)     users#show
```

You can use the `user_path(a_user)` and `user_url(a_user)` helpers:

```
[8] pry(main)> user_path(user_with_id_7)
=> "/users/7"
[9] pry(main)> user_url(user_with_id_7)
=> "http://localhost:3000/users/7"
[10] pry(main)>
```

Comment: This only work for 'new' urls. When trying to get a url for resource_path (show), it demands me to pass an id. But I would like to access something like /condominios/:id, interpolate the params with a map and call de url. I don't need to new if it is resource_a_path or resource_b_path. Is it possible?

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you wouldn't just use the show path version, which in my example would be `user_path` and pass in the user object. Isn't the interpolation reinventing the wheel for the Rails framework? I'll edit my answer to show the `show` case.

Comment: It would work, but once I have a table that lead to several resources, for exemple users, posts and comments, what I had in mind was do something like this: "what resource does this row represents? A comment? Right, give me the show url for a comment and interpolate with these param. Then, redirect".

To work the way you suggested, I would need to do if/else to use user_url, post_url or comments_url. And in my case I have nested resources too.

But I will do some testing....